# Rotating an array by position n

Tags: java, algorithm

> Input is  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
>
> If rotateOrder = 2
>
> Output should be  7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6
>
> If rotateOrder = 3
>
> Output should be  6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5

Here is my program to do it:

```
int [] unOrderedArr = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
        int  orderToRotate =2;

       for(int i = 0; i<orderToRotate; i++){

           for(int j = unOrderedArr.length-1; j>0; j--){
               int temp = unOrderedArr[j];
               unOrderedArr[j] = unOrderedArr[j-1];
               unOrderedArr[j-1] = temp;

           }

        }

       for(int j = 0; j<unOrderedArr.length; j++){
         System.out.println("element is " + unOrderedArr[j]);

           }
```

How can it be optimized?

Comment: You can use the ["Juggling Method"](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-rotation/) which is an in-place algorithm with complexity O(n).

Comment: Using [`System.arraycopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) is much faster than copying with a loop.  However, the original question possibly expected you to implement it using a looping algorithm.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Validate your inputs

The current method doesn't check for invalid input:

- `null` array
- negative rotation order

I suggest to add this ad the top:

```
if (arr == null || order < 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("The array must be non-null and the order must be non-negative");
}
```

#### Follow standard formatting

The posted code is messy. Use your IDE to reformat it to the standard:

```
int[] unOrderedArr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
int orderToRotate = 2;

for (int i = 0; i < orderToRotate; i++) {
    for (int j = unOrderedArr.length - 1; j > 0; j--) {
        int temp = unOrderedArr[j];
        unOrderedArr[j] = unOrderedArr[j - 1];
        unOrderedArr[j - 1] = temp;
    }
}
```

Now that's a lot easier to read.

On a related note, an easy way to print an array is using `Arrays.toString`

#### Optimize

Frist of all,
what will happen if you receive `arr` to rotate, and the rotate order = `arr.length`?
The array elements will be rotated pointlessly,
just to return to their original position.
This gets even worse for multiples of `arr.length`.

Secondly, in this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < order; i++) {
    for (int j = arr.length - 1; j > 0; j--) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The above code iterates over the entire array `order` times.

To avoid unnecessary iterations,
you will benefit from using a clone of the original array,
and iterate over the elements only once,
at the expense of using twice as much memory.

#### Suggested implementation

The above suggestions and some style improvements applied:

```
private static void rotate(int[] arr, int order) {
    if (arr == null || order < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The array must be non-null and the order must be non-negative");
    }
    int offset = arr.length - order % arr.length;
    if (offset > 0) {
        int[] copy = arr.clone();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
            int j = (i + offset) % arr.length;
            arr[i] = copy[j];
        }
    }
}
```

Some unit test to verify it works:

```
@Test
public void testRotateBy2() {
    int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    int[] expected = {7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    rotate(arr, 2);
    assertArrayEquals(expected, arr);
}

@Test
public void testRotateBy3() {
    int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    int[] expected = {6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    rotate(arr, 3);
    assertArrayEquals(expected, arr);
}

@Test
public void testRotateByLength() {
    int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    int[] expected = arr.clone();
    rotate(arr, arr.length);
    assertArrayEquals(expected, arr);
    rotate(arr, arr.length * 3);
    assertArrayEquals(expected, arr);
}

@Test
public void testRotateByZero() {
    int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    int[] expected = arr.clone();
    rotate(arr, 0);
    assertArrayEquals(expected, arr);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a neat implementation ( following "Programming Pearls" ) that doesn't require temporary storage.

Assume that you have a method `reverse(int[] array, int i, int, j)` that reverses the portion of array between i and j (inclusive). Then `rotate(int[] array, int rotateOrder)` is implemented by (skipped boundary checks for berevity):

```
public rotate(int[] array, int k) {
    int lastIndex = array.length-1;
    
    reverse(array, 0, lastIndex);
    reverse(array, 0, k-1);
    reverse(array, k, lastIndex);
}


public void reverse(int[] a, int i , int j) {
    int ii =  i;
    int jj = j;

    while (ii < jj) {
        swap(ii, jj, a);
        ++ii;
        --jj;
    }
}
```

By having the call `reverse(array, 0, lastIndex)` be the last one, you get a rotation in the opposite direction

Comment: Turns out that this is how `Collections.rotate(List)` is implemented (for non trivial sized input)

Answer (score 3):

I would use different algorithm. Create new array and copy the data from the old one with an offset:

```
int[] rotate(final int[] unOrderedArr, final int orderToRotate) {
    final int length = unOrderedArr.length;
    final int[] rotated = new int[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        rotated[(i + orderToRotate) % length] = unOrderedArr[i];
    }
    return rotated;
}
```

It should be both simpler and faster - especially for big arrays and large offsets. The only downside is that you need to allocate additional array. For small offsets this might be the bottleneck. But, as always, you should benchmark first and identify which cases are worth optimizing.

Answer (score 1):

As per the code in question there are three  for loop to get the data. Here i am using only one for loop to get the element which we want to swap. Using java script in built functions to get the elements which we dont want to swap.

So steps are as follows:

1. Get array element which we don't want to swap store in temp array.
2. Check weather input element should not exceed the actual array length
3. Loop array element which we are swapping store in resultant array (result)
4. End Loop
5. Concat new array with slice array to get resultant output.
6. Print result

   ```
   var numberArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
   var maxLength = numberArr.length;
   var swapBy = 2;
   var temp = numberArr.slice(0, (maxLength - swapBy));
   var result = [];
   if(swapBy > maxLength) {
     alert("Sorry : Please enter proper  value");
   }
   for(var i = (maxLength - swapBy); i < maxLength; i++) {
     result.push(numberArr[i]);
   }
   result.concat(temp);
   //output will be
   //[5, 6 ,1, 2, 3, 4]
   ```

I think this is optimize solution time as well as for space

Answer (score 1):

Additional permutation of the solution.
Includes optimization reducing the amount of cycles needed if they exceed the array length

```
private int[] getCyclicInts(int[] A, int K) {
    if (A == null)
        return A;

    if (A.length <= 1)
        return A;

    if (K <= 0)
        return A;

    //make sure we don't do unneeded loops.
    int actualIteration = K;
    if (actualIteration >= A.length){
        actualIteration = actualIteration % A.length;
    }

    if (actualIteration == 0)
        return A;

    int []  array = new int [A.length];

    int index = 0;
    for (int i=A.length - actualIteration  ; i < A.length; i++){
        array[index] = A[i];
        index ++;
    }

    for (int i=0 ; i < A.length - actualIteration; i++){
        array[index] = A[i];
        index ++;
    }

    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the \$O(n)\$ time complexity . I see it as optimized version of accepted solution as in accepted solution we are making copy of complete array but in below solution i am only copying  the required elements instead of all. So better will be the memory space complexity though worst can be \$O(n)\$:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] unOrderedArr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    int rotationOrder = 3;

    /**
     * this will store the last n elements which need to be shifted in
     * beginning
     **/

    if (unOrderedArr.length != rotationOrder) {

        int[] temp = new int[rotationOrder];
        int tempPointer = unOrderedArr.length - rotationOrder;

        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; ++i) {
            temp[i] = unOrderedArr[tempPointer++];

        }

        for (int i = unOrderedArr.length - rotationOrder - 1; i >= 0; --i) {

            unOrderedArr[i + rotationOrder] = unOrderedArr[i];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; ++i) {
            unOrderedArr[i] = temp[i];

        }
    }

    // print the output
    for (int i = 0; i < unOrderedArr.length; ++i) {
        System.out.println(unOrderedArr[i]);

    }

}
```